# MongoDB Driver has aggregation pipeline?

Tags: php, mongodb

So I'm trying to use an Aggregation Pipeline to perform a left join operation in the database.

I always use MongoDB Driver to perform operations (`new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://localhost');`).

I haven't seen how to do an aggregation in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

The only way that I've seen, is using de Command line driver:

```
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'collection',
    'pipeline' => [
        ['$group' => ['_id' => '$y', 'sum' => ['$sum' => '$x']]],
    ],
    'cursor' => new stdClass,
]);
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('db', $command);
```

Comment: What is not working when you use `Command`?

Comment: @DanFromGermany that instead do a simple `$collection->aggregate()`, I've to open a manager and perform Command line stuff. So I ask, if there is a more simple and logical way to do that.

Comment: You could ignore the whole PHP stuff and run mongo via shell `shell_exec('mongo mongodb://yourhost/db your-mongo-aggregation.js');`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can make use of the `MongoCollection::aggregate` extension provided in the driver.
http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php